# Google Apps Script HTML drop down without Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script

I am working on an Apps Script for Chromebooks using https://github.com/NoSubstitute/CB_DeviceDetails as the base. On the pageSerial.html, line 47, I would like to not only show the OU the Chromebook is in but also have a drop-down box pulling all of my Workspace OUs, and I would like to be able to move the Chromebook to a chosen OU. I would also like the Asset ID to be an editable text box so that it can be updated. For the Asset ID, I have changed it to

```
            <td>Asset ID</td>
            <td><input type="text" style="border:solid;" name="AssetID" value="idCBassets" id="idCBassets"></td>
```

so that it is a text box, but I can't figure out how to make it update the device in Google.
Also, for the OU, I created a new gs page to test with

```
function listSubOUs() {
  var page = AdminDirectory.Orgunits.list('my_customer', {
      orgUnitPath: '/',
      type: 'all'
    });
    var orgUnits = page.organizationUnits;
    if (orgUnits) {
      for (var i = 0; i < orgUnits.length; i++) {
        var orgUnit = orgUnits[i];
        if (orgUnits[0].name) { var ouname = orgUnits[0].name } else { var ouname = "" };
        if (orgUnits[0].orgUnitPath) { var ou = orgUnits[0].orgUnitPath } else { var ou = "" };
      }
    } else {
      var ouname = 'No OUs found.';
      var ou = 'No OUs found.';
    }
}
```

which appears to work, but I don't know what to do with it. I have found tons of Apps Script examples that deal with Sheets, but nothing without it.

Thank you for your assistance.

**Edit**
After some digging, I have come up with this, but I don't know how correct it would be.

```
    var select = document.getElementById("selectCampus"); 
var options = [ouname]; 

for(var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
    var opt = options[i];
    var el = document.createElement("option");
    el.text = opt;
    el.value = opt;
    select.add(el);
}


<select id="selectCampus">
    <option>"idCBOUs"</option>
</select>


function moveCB(sernum) {
  var serno = sernum;
  // Since we provided serial numbers, convert each to device-id
  var sernoquery = "id:" + serno;
  // Use AdminSDK API to check if the cros device exists. Else the update will fail
  var chromebooklist = AdminDirectory.Chromeosdevices.list('my_customer', { query: sernoquery }).chromeosdevices;
  if (!chromebooklist) {
  } else if (chromebooklist.length !== 1) {
  } else {
    var id = chromebooklist[0].deviceId;
    // For each line, try to update the device with given data, and log the result
    try {
      AdminDirectory.Chromeosdevices.update({ orgUnitPath: ou }, 'my_customer', id);
    } catch (err) {
      return [serno, "couldn't be moved", "#ffc90e"];
    }
  }
  return [serno, "has been moved, clear requested", "#ba68c8"];
}
```

More digging and testing.

```js
    var ouArray = [];
    var page = AdminDirectory.Orgunits.list('my_customer', {
      orgUnitPath: '/',
      type: 'all'
    });
    var orgUnits = page.organizationUnits;
    if (orgUnits) {
      for (var i = 0; i < orgUnits.length; i++) {
        var orgUnit = orgUnits[i];
        if (orgUnits[0].name) { var ouname2 = orgUnits[0].name } else { var ouname2 = "" };
        if (orgUnits[0].orgUnitPath) { var ou2 = orgUnits[0].orgUnitPath } else { var ou2 = "" };
        ouArray.push(orgUnit.orgUnitPath);
      }
      ouArray.sort();
    } else {
      var ouname2 = 'No OUs found.';
      var ou2 = 'No OUs found.';
    }
```

This pulls all of my Google OUs properly

```js
var listOUs = CBOU[15]; // This grabs the incoming array into the listOUs var for reuse
    console.log(listOUs);
    let htmlT=`<select id="idOUs" value="${CBOU[6]}">`; // This was supposed to select the actual OU, but didn't quite work - see below for necessary code
    for (let i=0; i<listOUs.length; i++) {
      const optionT = listOUs[i].replace(/<|>/g,'');
      htmlT+=`<option ${optionT==CBOU[6]?`selected`:``} value="${optionT}">${optionT}</option>`;
    }
    htmlT+='</select>'
    console.log(htmlT);

    document.getElementById("selectinput").innerHTML = htmlT;
    var elems = document.querySelectorAll('select');
    var instances = M.FormSelect.init(elems);
```

This gives me the OUs into an array that does display appropriately on the page. I have added an Update button to the page to edit fields for the Chromebook, and it correctly populates in Google Admin. Still, I haven't figured out how to make it to where I change the OU in the drop-down and select Update for the OU to be updated.

Comment: I'm not that familiar with organizational units but it looks like you need to pass an array that contain ou name and perhaps id to your javascript function that creates the options for the select element

Comment: I was thinking that, but I can't figure out how to accomplish this. There are plenty of examples referencing a Google Sheet, but they are not standalone.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/orgunits#OrgUnit

Comment: Sorry for the delay in updating, but been trying hard to get this going.

Comment: Also, I am trying to rack my brain around splitting the OU at each / and making it a cascading drop-down. So, instead of just "/High School/ Grade 09/ Students", it could split it so that I can drop to High School, then over to Grade 09.